# Парсинг старых записей с исключением, если есть запись новее

Tags: mysql

Как отсеить в логах автоматически с помощью запроса логи, месячной давности, но очистить из них те, если есть новее.
Т.к запись идет в бд:

действие | таймстамп | логин

Пробовал вложенный селект исключающий запись при имеющейся записи новее но не пооучилось.

```
SELECT `login`, `timestamp` 
FROM `logs_accounts` 
WHERE `action` = 'login' 
  AND `timestamp` <= ? 
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
```

Просто суть в том, что хочу распарсить старые аккаунты, чтоб удалить их, по логам входов. Но, в timestamp <= ? попадают и активные аккаунты, из-за того, что INSERT INTO срабатывает всегда при входе.

Comment: лучше возьмите максимальные даты в разрезе логинов.

Comment: Есть такая функция `DATE_SUB` в `MySQL` вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064687/mysql-select-all-rows-from-last-month-until-now-1-month-for-comparative-p

Comment: После такого запроса БД зависает: 

"select `login` from `logs_accounts` t where t.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and not exists (SELECT `login` FROM `logs_accounts` WHERE t.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND t.login = logs_accounts.login)"